# Javascript permission denied when opener.reload

Tags: javascript, permission-denied, window.opener

I have a Rails app, in which there's

```
link_to 'Show', %Q[javascript:self.window.open('http://somelink.com', 'width=700,height=550,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes,toolbar=yes,status=yes').focus()]
```

When clicking on the link, a popup window is open in which there'a  `OK` button. If user clicks on the `OK` button, the popup supposes to be closed. The button works fine on Google Chrome but does not work in Firefox. Using Firebug to debug that, I see the function in the popup window gets permission denied. The code for the popup window is:

```
function onclick(event) {
 opener.top.location.reload();
 self.close();
}
```

The error message is: `Permission denied to access property 'reload'`

I was looking around but couldn't find a way to fix this. Apparently I don't have access to the code of the popup window.

Answer (score 2):

Is `opener.top` in the same 'Origin' (typically the same domain)? I would assume so since it works in Chrome. Perhaps this workaround works:

Call `opener.please_reload_for_me()`.

Where the opener frame has the function:

```
function please_reload_for_me() {
    window.top.reload();
}
```

So basically delegating the access of `top` to the opener frame.